# Insert in MySQL but override if foreign keys are identical

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on my first db and executing statements through java. I have 2 columns in the db named

Playername
PlayerType

I need to update the row if my query corresponds to these 2 columns.

So there can be multiple player names and multiple player types but never more than 1 exact player type and exact player name.

If the row doesn't exist create a new one. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: @Zelldon not at my computer but name is varchar(16) and so is playertype. I just couldn't figure out a way to insert where playername = getName() and playertype = getType().toString() what if the specified clause in where doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

You first have to set a multiple field primary key

```
CREATE TABLE Players
(
PlayerName varchar(16) NOT NULL, //Not null not required as it is part of pk but more readable
PlayerType varchar(16) NOT NULL,
//Other fields
CONSTRAINT pk_PlayersID PRIMARY KEY (PlayerName ,PlayerType )
)
```

And then you use

```
INSERT INTO Players(PlayerName , PlayerType ,....) VALUES(PN, PT, ....) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
PlayerName VALUES(PlayerName ), PlayerType =VALUES(PlayerType ),...
```

Comment: Thank you so much (: I will change how my table is setup.